# SQL Server increment rank Partition By split groupings of duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given a table like the following:

| Part | Batch | TransactionDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 2022-06-10 13:25:00 |
| 1 | 1001 | 2022-06-11 14:00:00 |
| 1 | 1002 | 2022-06-12 07:25:00 |
| 1 | 1002 | 2022-06-12 08:25:00 |
| 1 | 1002 | 2022-06-12 09:25:00 |
| 1 | 1001 | 2022-06-13 10:21:00 |
| 2 | 1003 | 2022-06-10 11:20:00 |
| 2 | 1004 | 2022-06-11 12:20:00 |

How can I rank by part and batch while ensuring the date/time order of TransactionDate column?

- The table should be ordered by Part followed by TransactionDate
- When there is a new part, the rank should restart from 1
- Each block of consecutive part/batch should receive the same rank
- When a batch changes from row to row within the same part (even if batch is a previous one from some row above), the rank should be incremented by 1
- the number of rows in each consecutive block of part/batch numbers can vary

So I should get the following table:

| Part | Batch | TransactionDate | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 2022-06-10 13:25:00 | 1 |
| 1 | 1001 | 2022-06-11 14:00:00 | 1 |
| 1 | 1002 | 2022-06-12 07:25:00 | 2 |
| 1 | 1002 | 2022-06-12 08:25:00 | 2 |
| 1 | 1002 | 2022-06-12 09:25:00 | 2 |
| 1 | 1001 | 2022-06-13 10:21:00 | 3 |
| 2 | 1003 | 2022-06-13 11:20:00 | 1 |
| 2 | 1004 | 2022-06-13 12:20:00 | 2 |

I was thinking of using dense rank in a partition such as the below:

`DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Part, Batch ORDER BY TransactionDate)`

However, the above combines all part and batch combinations into subsequent rows and then orders by transaction date. Therefore, it ranks all part/batch combinations (of 1 and 1001 respectively) as 1. But I need it to respect the transaction date order as in the table above.

Any help on a query to do the above would be appreciated.

EDIT: the number of rows in each consecutive block of part/batch numbers can vary.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be:

- creating a column that assigns `1` when the "*Batch*" current value is different from the "*Batch*" value lagged one row, `0`, partitioned by "*Part*" otherwise
- computing a running sum over this boolean value on the same partitions

Here's the full query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           CASE WHEN Batch 
                  <> LAG(Batch, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY Part ORDER BY TransactionDate)
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 0
                END AS new_batch
    FROM tab
)
SELECT Part, 
       Batch,
       TransactionDate,
       ExpectedRank,
       1+SUM(new_batch) OVER(PARTITION BY Part ORDER BY TransactionDate) AS rank
FROM cte
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ab2e5ef938e2d226e195670c03131659).

Comment: whilst the above solves the exact example I presented, I believe it assumes there can only ever be one row of a different part/batch combination as a separation (row 3 in my example). I should have stated that the number of consecutive rows for each block of part/batch combination is unknown. Could your solution be adapted for this or do you have any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Sure thing @elsami, could you provide a bigger sample data?

Comment: I have reworded my originally question as I realised I wasn't asking for what I actually wanted. I have also provided a better sample dataset. Any support is appreciated.

Comment: It is even simpler. Check the updated answer. @elsami

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense. Although, I have come across an edge case. When there are two duplicate date/times from different batch numbers, the rank is incremented when it shouldn't. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5a69ba7a9170b6377488fa94b14d597c

Comment: I realised I have to order by TransactionDate and then Batch in the ORDER BY statement to ensure batches are in right order for duplicate dates.

Comment: Yeah I was about to tell that to you: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=50148c455fd4702083020342c9e9a375. My only change was in the ORDER BY inside the SUM, but I don't know if ordering descendently on the batch is a correct assumption. Is it?

Comment: The actual problem is that there's no column in your data that specifies a specific order between rows when transaction_date is the same. My suggestion is to either include date as a timestamp (with the time) or add an integer ranking column, if no other assumption can be made with the current data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245621/discussion-between-elsami-and-lemon).